# Set parameters in a stored procedure that returns a resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vba

I'm trying to consolidate some code but before I open this particular can of worms I wanted to find out from you guys.  If I have several stored procedures...

sproc1 - "master proc" which sets @test

sproc2 - proc that executes if @test exists and returns both a resultset and (if possible) resets @serial

sproc3 - proc that executes if @test does not exist and returns both a resultset and (if possible) resets @serial

**sproc1**

```
    @leftStack INT,
    @leftTray INT,
    @midStack INT,
    @midTray INT,
    @rightStack INT,
    @rightTray INT

    AS


    DECLARE @soLineNumber varchar(50)
    DECLARE @serial VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @rack INT
    DECLARE @tray INT
    DECLARE @position INT

    SELECT @test = oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
        FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL
            WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            ( 
            SELECT [SERIAL_NUMBER] 
                FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL 
                    WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] 
            ) 
            AND NOT EXISTS 
                ( 
                SELECT [SERIAL_NUMBER] 
                    FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_INSERTED] AS oI 
                        WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = oI.[SERIAL_NUMBER] 
                ) 
    --      AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = @soLineNumber --pick regardless of SO line number, to reduce gaps between lines
            AND ((oL.[RACK] = @leftStack AND oL.[TRAY] = @leftTray) 
            OR (oL.[RACK] = @midStack AND oL.[TRAY] = @midTray) 
            OR (oL.[RACK] = @rightStack AND oL.[TRAY] = @rightTray))
         ORDER BY [SO_LINE_NUMBER] ASC
IF NULLIF(@test, '') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sproc2
    END
IF NULLIF(@test, '') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sproc3
    END

UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] SET [PICKED] = 'True' WHERE [SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial
END
```

My questions:
1) how can I reset @serial from sproc2 and sproc3?

2) in an ADO recordset query, will the results from the executed stored procedures pull in, if so, how?

Comment: @test will only be available in sproc1.  That's how temporary tables and variables work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work `sproc2` and `sproc3` should been defined like this:

```
CREATE PROC sproc2 @test VARCHAR(50), @serial VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
```

What this does is, it sends the value of `@test` as a value param. The `OUTPUT` keyword on `@serial` enables you to keep track of any changes done on `@serial`.

Comment: how do you execute sproc1 as well as handle `@serial` in sproc1?

Comment: If I execute sproc1 from ADO, will the resultsets from sproc 2 or 3 produce as expected?  i.e. if I `select col1, col2, col3 from table` in sproc2, will col1, col2, and col3 show as recordset results from executing sproc1?